# Create dynamic input for variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I hope someone can help, I am new to programming, my problem is this:

40 checkboxes on a form which one by one, needs to be checked for boolean "True" or "False" (checked or unchecked by user), so that I can run individual code for each "True" case.

I am trying to include a counter "i" in the "MS Access checkbox reference" which I use for the variable, to give me the value of the given checkbox. The following code should show what I try to accomplish, can anybody point me in the right direction, without using a very advanced solution? I presume it is because it cannot execute all of this in a single step or because it only sees my input for the variable as a string and not a command to execute :

```
Do While Flag = True

Dim CheckboxVar As Boolean
i = i + 1

If i = 40 Then
    Flag = False
End If

CheckboxVar = "Me.Checkbox" & i & ".Value"
AddWhereSQL = SQLBuilder (CheckboxVar)
Loop
```

(Retrieve the value of Checkbox1 and send it to SQLBuilder, retrieve Checkbox2 and send it to SQLBuilder, and so on)

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, for my case and persona, Kostas K's solution works best (It is implemented and running). I use the name of the control instead of tag, and I run individual/unique code depending on which checkbox is True. This site is a wonderful place with wonderful people, thank you very much. Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through the controls, you can do this:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 40
    If Me.Controls("CheckBoxControlName" & i).Value = -1 Then
        'The control value is True
    End If
Next i
```

If you code is placed in a Standard Module, change `Me` to `Forms!YourFormName`.

Comment: Small note: use an integer instead of a long to save memory and execution time (the max value is 40)

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth VBA internally converts all Integers to Long therefore there's no performance advantage.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth. I learnt something new today as well (thanks Kostas K.!) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long

Comment: @KostasK. Thanks for the heads up, sorry for the incorrect criticism. Guess I can go optimize literally all code that uses integers I ever wrote.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth Ah, no bother man. I had to do the exact same thing when I found out. :)

Answer (score 5):

Loop through your checkboxes like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            If ctrl.Value = True Then
                'do something
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Naming your checkboxes *"Checkbox1", "Checkbox2", etc*. is tiresome and not the best naming practice. The code above will find every checkbox on the form but you could easily restrict it to all checkboxes with a specific tag, for example.

Comment: Note that you may have to account for checkboxes that shouldn't be in the loop. You can use tags for that (e.g. set a tag for all checkboxes that should, and check `If ctrl.Tag = "something" Then`)

Comment: Your code applies to Userforms, but not to Access forms (they are not MSForms). -- With 40 checkboxes on a form, chances are that the *only* sensible way to name them is `Checkbox1`, `Checkbox2`, ...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, tagging works -- for the same reason I suggested putting them all in a frame and looping through `UserForm1.Frame1.Controls`, for example.

Comment: @CallumDA Yes, but like Andre said, it's an Access question and not a userform, so frames are unavailable. Tags are the usual way for Access. Your further code will work fine after minor changes (remove `MSForms.`, change `UserForm1` to `Me`)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I don't have Access so I can't test it but good to know! Please feel free to edit this answer and change the declarations so that it's more suitable for OP.

Comment: Adjusted for use in MS Access, @Andre it should be fine now, I agree with CallumDA that Checkbox1, Checkbox2 etc. should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a "for" loop. Maybe something like:

```
CheckboxVar = " WHERE "
For i = 1 to 40
    CheckboxVar = Me.Controls("Checkbox" & i).Value = True & " AND " & checkboxVar
next
```